# Questions about "Obscure" cursor facts

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know a set based solution is ideal and generally superior to a cursor. So please. Save your and mine time by abstaining from answers "don't use cursor, use set based ops". I am asking this because my Googling has not given any answers and the knowledge probably comes from experience:

1) **FETCH NEXT FROM vs FETCH FROM** When i open up a cursor (fast_forward/static), is there a difference between using 'fetch next from' and 'fetch next' inside the while loop? In performance, order of records accessed etc.

2) **ROW_NUMBER + SELECT/WHILE vs STATIC CURSOR** As I understand it,  a static cursor creates a temp table with the data selected and goes over this temp table. So, is there any reason to use `select row_number() ..., ... from ... into ...` and iterate over it with a index variable and `select * from #tmp table where RowNumber = @IndexVar`?

3) **FAST_FORWARD - can it break down?** if i have a fast_forward local cursor, and inside this cursor insert/update operations are performed on tables the cursor selects from, are there any issues? (possible cycles etc?)

4) **PLAN FORCING** Is there a way to force a fast_forward cursor to use static/dynamic plan?

Thank you very much for your answers

PS: For those of you really curious, yes, the problem could be rewritten into a set-based approach, but due to some decisions from higher-up, new rows created in the primary table have to be created/inserted using a stored procedure.

Comment: And how would having a stored proc prevent you from using a set-based approach? Stored procs can be written to use set-based code.

Comment: This looks like multiple questions in one.  Perhaps consider breaking each of your numbers into a separate question?

Comment: @HLGEM: if you mean executing a stored procedure where the stored procedure does a set-based insert/update...NO. Why?
1st) right now its a stored procedure that goes through a cursor and cals a stored procedure .. lets call it CreateUpdateRecord. This procedure creates/updates one and one record only, you can think of it as a constructor/setter from a standart language like c#. This was done before i joined the project and for now, i cannot do anything about it. Asked about it, this a a hard fact that wont change anytime soon. My only option is to execute it 450 000 as fast as possible.

Comment: You didn't indicate the stored proc was already written. However, consider that stored procs can now take arrays as input variables and thus move from processing one to many records. At least you tried though. I too have seen some stupid decisions like this where we were told to use a service to insert or update records and yes a 1,500,000 record file took literally days to process on prod and we don't do it any longer. Sometimes you just have to show them the stupidity of the idea by doing it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a difference between using 'fetch next from' and 'fetch next' inside the while loop

No - `NEXT` is the default if no option is specified

> So, is there any reason to use `select row_number() ..., ... from ... into ...` and iterate over it with a index variable and `select * from #tmp table where RowNumber = @IndexVar`?

I would presume that a static cursor has optimizations that would perform faster that you creating a temp table and searching for a specific row in each iteration, but I'd have to try it.

> if i have a fast_forward local cursor, and inside this cursor insert/update operations are performed on tables the cursor selects from, are there any issues? (possible cycles etc?)

I'm not sure what you mean by "cycles" - if the underlying data changes the cursor will change as well (unless you declared it as `STATIC`)

> Is there a way to force a fast_forward cursor to use static/dynamic plan?

I've never tried it, but you could try using `OPTION( USE PLAN ...)` in your `SELECT` when you define the cursor. I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work.

> i am getting mad about this and google is clueless

Google just reports what people put on the internet... Why are you mad?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i am getting mad about a 400k record insert taking more then 40 minutes (still running when i left) while a 100k takes about 4 minutes. As for - "if the underlying data changes the cursor will change as well" - just if i understand this corectly: doing a fast_forward cursor over a table of about 400 000 records and during this process inserting about 1500 and updating the other 385k records could lead to cursor being rebuild over and over again?

Comment: well, the cursor insert/update cycle for 400k records broke down after 6hours (let it run during night, transaction log got to about 29gb), broke down on HDD full. in one cursor cycle about 30 insert/updates (one row each) is done

Answer (score 0):

1. `NEXT` is the default fetch option, so `FETCH` = `FETCH NEXT`
2. Static/Dynamic refers to whether or not changes made by the cursor result set are reflected, ie if you insert new values into the static cursor result set it will not loop through those, it's whatever results are there when the cursor is declared/opened, and that's it, I believe your understanding is correct.
3. I'm not sure.
4. I'm not sure what you mean here, you can indicate dynamic or static when you declare your cursor.